Electric pair mode in the shell - only consider current line?
When I'm using electric-pair-mode in an M-x shell, it will treat the output of commands as candidates to pair with, so if there's a mis-match, it won't work correctly - e.g. if everything is balanced, but then suddenly this happens:
"""  # <- last line from a python diff, for example
$

Then electric pair won't give me two "'s when I type a quote, as it thinks I'm finishing a pair.
Is there either:

A way I can get electric-pair-mode to only consider the buffer from the last prompt? Or
Another similar mode that can/will fix this?


I think you want to (setq electric-pair-preserve-balance nil). It will always give you the pair, disregarding the "balancing state".
I think it may be possible to hack the mode so it only takes the current line for context, but see if changing electric-pair-preserve-balance works well enough for you.
